# How to make a custom field that can add multiple images

Tags: 8

I want to create a custom field that can embed multiple images and multiple texts with drupal 8.

I thought of inheriting the ImageItem class and expressing it, but I felt that it could not be in multiple image fields. (I am wrong?)
So I decided to extend the FieldItemBase class.

First of all, I tried to simply display the image.

FieldType:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\sample\Plugin\Field\FieldType;

use Drupal\Component\Render\PlainTextOutput;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Bytes;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\StreamWrapperInterface;


/**
 * Provides a field type of baz.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "simple_image_item",
 *   label = @Translation("メインビジュアル"),
 *   default_formatter = "simple_image_formatter",
 *   default_widget = "simple_image_widget",
 * )
 */
class SimpleImageItem extends FieldItemBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function defaultStorageSettings() {
    return [
      'target_type' => 'file',
      'display_field' => FALSE,
      'display_default' => FALSE,
      'uri_scheme' => file_default_scheme(),
    ] + parent::defaultStorageSettings();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function defaultFieldSettings() {
    return [
      'file_extensions' => 'png gif jpg jpeg',
      'file_directory' => '[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]',
      'max_filesize' => '10MB',
      'description_field' => 0,
    ] + parent::defaultFieldSettings();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fieldSettingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element = [];
    $settings = $this->getSettings();

    // Make the extension list a little more human-friendly by comma-separation.
    $extensions = str_replace(' ', ', ', $settings['file_extensions']);
    $element['file_extensions'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Allowed file extensions'),
      '#default_value' => $extensions,
      '#description' => t('Separate extensions with a space or comma and do not include the leading dot.'),
      '#element_validate' => [[get_class($this), 'validateExtensions']],
      '#weight' => 1,
      '#maxlength' => 256,
      // By making this field required, we prevent a potential security issue
      // that would allow files of any type to be uploaded.
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $element['file_directory'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('File directory'),
      '#default_value' => $settings['file_directory'],
      '#description' => t('Optional subdirectory within the upload destination where files will be stored. Do not include preceding or trailing slashes.'),
      '#element_validate' => [[get_class($this), 'validateDirectory']],
      '#weight' => 3,
    ];

    $element['max_filesize'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Maximum upload size'),
      '#default_value' => $settings['max_filesize'],
      '#description' => t('Enter a value like "512" (bytes), "80 KB" (kilobytes) or "50 MB" (megabytes) in order to restrict the allowed file size. If left empty the file sizes will be limited only by PHP\'s maximum post and file upload sizes (current limit <strong>%limit</strong>).', ['%limit' => format_size(file_upload_max_size())]),
      '#size' => 10,
      '#element_validate' => [[get_class($this), 'validateMaxFilesize']],
      '#weight' => 5,
    ];

    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function storageSettingsForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $has_data) {
    $element = [];

    $element['#attached']['library'][] = 'file/drupal.file';

    $element['display_field'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Enable <em>Display</em> field'),
      '#default_value' => $this->getSetting('display_field'),
      '#description' => t('The display option allows users to choose if a file should be shown when viewing the content.'),
    ];

    $element['display_default'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Files displayed by default'),
      '#default_value' => $this->getSetting('display_default'),
      '#description' => t('This setting only has an effect if the display option is enabled.'),
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="settings[display_field]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $scheme_options = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getNames(StreamWrapperInterface::WRITE_VISIBLE);
    $element['uri_scheme'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Upload destination'),
      '#options' => $scheme_options,
      '#default_value' => $this->getSetting('uri_scheme'),
      '#description' => t('Select where the final files should be stored. Private file storage has significantly more overhead than public files, but allows restricted access to files within this field.'),
      '#disabled' => $has_data,
    ];

    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * Form API callback
   *
   * Removes slashes from the beginning and end of the destination value and
   * ensures that the file directory path is not included at the beginning of the
   * value.
   *
   * This function is assigned as an #element_validate callback in
   * fieldSettingsForm().
   */
  public static function validateDirectory($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Strip slashes from the beginning and end of $element['file_directory'].
    $value = trim($element['#value'], '\\/');
    $form_state->setValueForElement($element, $value);
  }

  /**
   * Form API callback.
   *
   * This function is assigned as an #element_validate callback in
   * fieldSettingsForm().
   *
   * This doubles as a convenience clean-up function and a validation routine.
   * Commas are allowed by the end-user, but ultimately the value will be stored
   * as a space-separated list for compatibility with file_validate_extensions().
   */
  public static function validateExtensions($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if (!empty($element['#value'])) {
      $extensions = preg_replace('/([, ]+\.?)/', ' ', trim(strtolower($element['#value'])));
      $extensions = array_filter(explode(' ', $extensions));
      $extensions = implode(' ', array_unique($extensions));
      if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]+([.][a-z0-9])* ?)+$/', $extensions)) {
        $form_state->setError($element, t('The list of allowed extensions is not valid, be sure to exclude leading dots and to separate extensions with a comma or space.'));
      }
      else {
        $form_state->setValueForElement($element, $extensions);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Form API callback.
   *
   * Ensures that a size has been entered and that it can be parsed by
   * \Drupal\Component\Utility\Bytes::toInt().
   *
   * This function is assigned as an #element_validate callback in
   * fieldSettingsForm().
   */
  public static function validateMaxFilesize($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if (!empty($element['#value']) && !is_numeric(Bytes::toInt($element['#value']))) {
      $form_state->setError($element, t('The "@name" option must contain a valid value. You may either leave the text field empty or enter a string like "512" (bytes), "80 KB" (kilobytes) or "50 MB" (megabytes).', ['@name' => $element['title']]));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Determines the URI for a file field.
   *
   * @param array $data
   *   An array of token objects to pass to Token::replace().
   *
   * @return string
   *   An unsanitized file directory URI with tokens replaced. The result of
   *   the token replacement is then converted to plain text and returned.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\Core\Utility\Token::replace()
   */
  public function getUploadLocation($data = []) {
    return static::doGetUploadLocation($this->getSettings(), $data);
  }

  /**
   * Determines the URI for a file field.
   *
   * @param array $settings
   *   The array of field settings.
   * @param array $data
   *   An array of token objects to pass to Token::replace().
   *
   * @return string
   *   An unsanitized file directory URI with tokens replaced. The result of
   *   the token replacement is then converted to plain text and returned.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\Core\Utility\Token::replace()
   */
  protected static function doGetUploadLocation(array $settings, $data = []) {
    $destination = trim($settings['file_directory'], '/');

    // Replace tokens. As the tokens might contain HTML we convert it to plain
    // text.
    $destination = PlainTextOutput::renderFromHtml(\Drupal::token()->replace($destination, $data));
    return $settings['uri_scheme'] . '://' . $destination;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the upload validators for a file field.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An array suitable for passing to file_save_upload() or the file field
   *   element's '#upload_validators' property.
   */
  public function getUploadValidators() {
    $validators = [];
    $settings = $this->getSettings();

    // Cap the upload size according to the PHP limit.
    $max_filesize = Bytes::toInt(file_upload_max_size());
    if (!empty($settings['max_filesize'])) {
      $max_filesize = min($max_filesize, Bytes::toInt($settings['max_filesize']));
    }

    // There is always a file size limit due to the PHP server limit.
    $validators['file_validate_size'] = [$max_filesize];

    // Add the extension check if necessary.
    if (!empty($settings['file_extensions'])) {
      $validators['file_validate_extensions'] = [$settings['file_extensions']];
    }

    return $validators;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $schema["columns"] = [
      'bgPC_id' => [
        'description' => "PC用背景画像のファイルID",
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
      ],
    ];

    $schema['foreign keys'] = [
      'bgPC_id' => [
        'table' => 'file_managed',
        'columns' => ['bgPC_id' => 'fid'],
      ],
    ];
    $schema["indexes"] = [];
    return $schema;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties = [];

    $properties['bgPC_id'] = DataDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('pc file id'))
      ->setDescription(t("PC用背景画像のファイルID"));

    return $properties;
  }
}

?>
```

FieldWidget:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\sample\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\file\Element\ManagedFile;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'sample' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "simple_image_widget",
 *   label = @Translation("sample default"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "simple_image_item"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class SimpleImageWidget extends WidgetBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

      $element = [
        'bgPC_id' => [
          '#title' => t('PC用背景画像'),
          '#type' => 'managed_file',
          '#upload_location' => $items[$delta]->getUploadLocation(),
          '#upload_validators' => $items[$delta]->getUploadValidators(),
          '#value_callback' => [get_class($this), 'value'],
          '#empty_value' => '',
        ],
      ];

      return $element;
    }

    /**
     * Form API callback. Retrieves the value for the file_generic field element.
     *
     * This method is assigned as a #value_callback in formElement() method.
     */
    public static function value($element, $input, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

      // We depend on the managed file element to handle uploads.
      $return = ManagedFile::valueCallback($element, $input, $form_state);

      return $return;
    }

    public static function getFileId($target) {
      $fid = null;
      if (!empty($target) && is_array($target) && !empty($target[0])) {
        if ( is_int($target[0]) ) {
          $fid = $target[0];
        } else {
          $fid =  (int)$target[0];
        }
      }
      elseif (is_int($target)) {
        $fid = $target;
      }
      return $fid;
    }
  }
?>
```

I created the above two files.
Then I got this error:

> "This value should be of the correct primitive type"

I do not know why this happened.
Please tell me how to fix it.

I'm sorry if I said something wrong because  I'm Japanese and drupal beginner.
And I'm glad if you will tell me where I am being wrong.

thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using paragraphs to solve this problem rather than writing a custom module?

Comment: Mr.AlfredArmstrong

No, I was not considering it.

I did not know the existence of it.

I will try it right away.


Thank you for teaching me! :-)

Comment: Great. I'm sure there are tutorials online that can help as well. Paragraphs is a very powerful module, worth spending some time studying how to get the best out of it. Good luck.

Comment: The module you taught me was just the feature I wanted to realize!
Thank you very much!